# Are there any image manipulation tools for a website that don't require installation?

Tags: cms, images, tools

Are there any tools for to manipulate images that don't require installation. 
Or better put, imagemagik and GD both require installing, whereas something like jwplayer or ckeditor (not image related I know) do not. I'm looking for something I can bundle in with a custom CMS for users to copy the files and then work straight off the bat.

Nothing fancy, simple image resizing is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there are no image-handling libraries written in pure PHP. It wouldn't make any sense to do this since these kind of functions require fast native code to run - using PHP would be very slow.

I think most servers have GD and/or ImageMagick installed these days so it would be best to use those if they are available, and disallow the feature if they are not installed.

One alternative may be to use a web-based resizing tool. Apparently Flickr uses [Picnik.com](http://www.picnik.com/info/api) to resize its images (I don't know if there is any charge). Or if you have your own server with GD installed you could make your own service for use with your own software.

Comment: Thank you, yes picnik is free for non commercial use which suites my needs fine, will have a bash with it. Also looking into a few JQuery plug-ins. Thanks Again.